# Following artists by users - few questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I've made my own app basing on the railstutorial.org website, and i'm now on [chapter 11](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top). Everything's fine, i've learned a lot from this tutorial and now i'm continuing work on my app and i'm actually on model  "Artists" where every user can create new artist ex.Michael Hartl ;) and add their most popular quotations. The problem is to allow users to follow their favourite artists and see quotations in feed, just like Microposts feed from railstutorial. Artist and User are two different models, and railstutorial dosn't explaing how to make the "follow system" for that. It's like subscribing channels on YouTube etc. 
Can someone explain me how to get this working? What must i change in code?

**Answer**:

The button:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.userartists.build(followed_id: @artist.id)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

> ```
> class UserartistsController < ApplicationController
> def create
> @artist = Artist.find(params[:userartist][:followed_id])
> current_user.follow!(@artist)
> respond_to do |format|
> format.html { redirect_to @artist }
> format.js
> end
> end
> end
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set up a Artist model and a intermediate model called `UserArtist` (or `UserFollowsArtist`) where you will store all the matches between users and artists.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_artists
   has_many :artists, :through => :user_artists
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_artists
   has_many :users, :through => :user_artists
end

class UserArtist < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :artist
end
```

Now you can call `@user = User.first` to get the first user, and `@user.artists` to get the list of artists the `@user` is following.

You will have to create a separate controller called `UserArtistsController` where you will have actions `create` and possibly `destroy` (if the user wishes to unfollow the artist).

In your `routes.rb`:

`resources :user_artists, :only => [:create, :destroy]`

I guess the `follow button` will be on the `Artists` show page so you should have something like this in your view:

```
<%= button_to "Follow artist", {:controller => :user_artists,
      :action => 'create', :artist_id => params[:id] }, :method => :post %>
```

And in your controller:

```
class UserArtistsController < ActionController
def create 
    @user_artist = UserArtist.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :artist_id => params[:artist_id])
    @artist = Artist.find(params[:artist_id])
    if @user_artist.save
       redirect_to @artist
    else
       flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong, please try again"
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

end
```

Don't forget to create a migration for the `Artist` and `UserArtist`. `UserArtist` table should contain a `user_id` and a `artist_id`.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this is not working. There are couple of issues with this method and after whole week of working, i need to try done this by other way.

Comment: When i click "Follow" on artist page,  it's reloads the site again and shows me button "unfollow", so i think it's working now. When i look in database (rails c) by typing `@user = User.first` and then  `@user.artists`, it shows me only `" => [] "`.

 I was thinking a lot about this and i really don't know why it's not working for me.

Comment: if you post your code on github i can take a look and try to help you if i can

Comment: are you sure you are following the artist with the first user?

Comment: Yes, i have only one user in database. I'll try do this once more, i think that i know why it is not working. When I will know more, I will add new comment, and then we will see what can we do with this, if it still won't work. Have a nice day ;)

Comment: So, when i in console type `@user.userartists.create(artist_id: 19)` everything is fine, but i can't follow artists clicking the button. I think, that the problem is in that button: `<%= button_to "Follow artist", {:controller => :user_artists,
      :action => 'create', :artist_id => params[:id] }, :method => :post %>` What do you think about it? Did you have any other ideas on how the button can work?

Comment: There are no errors, when i click on the button, nothing happens.

Comment: it doesn't redirect you to somewhere? a few comments ago you said :`When i click "Follow" on artist page, it's reloads the site again and shows me button "unfollow"`

Comment: Yes, it was so before, now i have written this again, and it isn't working anymore.

Comment: if you post your code on github or the view where you are calling everthing, the controller and the three models on https://gist.github.com/ i could help you maybe. this way i can't

Comment: I've added my solution in first post. Thank you for your patience :)